# How to send event to all listeners/subscribers asynchronously?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

We have broadcaster service which maintains a list of listeners. Method invoked by broadcaster is blocking. How can I convert it to asynchronous or send event to all listeners in a non-blocking way. Is creating thread for each invocation is the only way?

```
public class EventBroadCaster {
List<Listener> allListeners = new ArrayList();

private void sendEventToAll() {
    for(Listener listener:allListeners)
        listener.accept(String event);
}
}

public interface Listener {
    public void accept(String event);
}
```

Structure is something like this, problem is accept(String event) method is blocking, and EventBroadCaster have to wait till accept on one listener is finished before invoking accept on another.
Is there a way to make accept method return immediately?

allListeners can have 100s of Listeners in it, don't want to create 100s of thread for each accept.

Comment: your question is not very clear kindly elaborate further

Comment: Explain *exactly* what the chain of events is - what calls what and when. What method is blocking, what does it do, and what does it block?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? You should [edit] it into your question.

Comment: @AustineGwa looks OK now?

Comment: This sounds like a design flaw. Your accept methods block!? You could use an executor service and call using multiple threads. Then as long as too many don't block your fine. You could also try using a parallel stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use,

```
String event = "wow events are strings";
allListeners.stream().parallel().forEach(l->l.accept(event));
```

Or you could explicitly use an ExecutorService.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
...
...

List<Callable> tasks = allListeners.stream().map(l->{ l.accept(event); return l;}).collect(Collectors.toList());

service.invokeAll(tasks);
```

That will block until everybody is notified, but it will notify in parallel. There are many variations on that could avoid blocking.

One such example, though not recommended, would be to fire and forget.

```
allListeners.forEach(l->service.execute(()->l.accept(event)));
```

This would stop the broadcast method blocking, but if too many accepts cause blocking, all of your threads could get gummed up.

I feel the actual solution is to fix the accept methods. Similar to how the EDT (event dispatch thread) works. You can have your ActionListener take a long time, but it will cause the gui to pause. Instead you have the action listener spawn a task that so the EDT doesn't have to wait.

Also, you might look into RxJava.

Comment: Thanks Matt, how can I avoid blocking?

Comment: I added a version that wouldn't block.

Comment: @Manish The real solution is in the last paragraph - events listeners/handlers code should usually return quickly. It's up to each of the handling logic to decide whether the execution is quick enough so that it doesn't "block enough" or to spawn a new task/thread/service... that will be executed in the background.

Comment: @matt I like the fire and forget approach. That's what I was looking for. Why you are not recommending it? A bit new to multi threading.

Comment: @matt  I understand the last approach is ideal but I was thinking if it is a good idea to be at mercy of Listeners to finish accept block fast. One bad implementation of accept method and all the notification will be delayed.

Comment: @Manish It is two things. a) It is a little incomplete, for exampl could monitor futures and check for exceptions. But that would be task specific. Maybe fire and forget is fine. b) The tasks should probably handle their own threading. eg. A long running task should be sent to an appropriate executor service from the accept method. That way appropriate logging exception handling occur. From the sounds of it, accept is a very generic method, where the consequences can be quite varied. Maybe fire and forget suits your task.